# Why does my macro stop at an .Unprotect instruction and then carry on unhindered when I continue it without changing anything?

Tags: excel, vba

Part of the macro takes an existing workbook and copies a bunch of the sheets to a new workbook. One of the copied sheets (SETTINGS) is protected in the original workbook.

In the new workbook, I need to make a quick change to the SETTINGS sheet so need to unprotect it first. This is how I've tried to do it:

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    If .Worksheets("SETTINGS").ProtectContents = True Then
        .Worksheets("SETTINGS").Unprotect
    End If
End With
```

But the macro will stop at the Unprotect line, saying that the worksheet is protected. Well, yeah. Then in the debugger I just click on the Run button and it carries on as if there is no problem.

I'm not sure why it keeps stopping? The sheet is not password protected, just lazily 'protected'.

I've added a wait loop between creating the new workbook and the attempt to unprotect the sheet:

```
Do While Not Application.Ready = True
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
Loop
```

But it hasn't helped.

Edit:

I changed it to:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With ActiveWorkbook
    If .Worksheets("SETTINGS").ProtectContents = True Then
        .Worksheets("SETTINGS").Unprotect
    End If
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

As per @black-cat's suggestion, but then it stopped at the 'Application.DisplayAlerts = False' line!

Answer (score 1):

Use DisplayAlerts property like this

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With ActiveWorkbook
    If .Worksheets("SETTINGS").ProtectContents = True Then
        .Worksheets("SETTINGS").Unprotect
    End If
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: If I put this at the start of the macro, will it prevent real errors from stopping the macro?

Comment: Ah, just realised. I have got this at the start of my macro, but at the point of creating the new file, I guess it's a new application and needs to be told separately to ignore the alerts. Thanks!

Comment: It didn't work :-(